# console is throwing undefined while me trying to Create an element for the Event listener to read

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a todo list webapp and serves as my basic training ground for javascript but the console is throwing errors and I can figure out. it says todo is undefined but I defined it through the function as a div to be created. I just wanted that every input on the form will be added on to my unordered list . I just use a sample value, not the real input. I so confused rn. thanks for your help.

```js
//selectors

const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector("todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector("todo-list");

//event listener
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);
console.log(event);

//functions
function addTodo(event) {

  //creating the Todo Div
  const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo");

  //creating the LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = "A new Task";
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

  //checkmark button
  const completedButtton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButtton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check></i>';
  completedButtton.classList.add('complete-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButtton);

  //trash button
  const trashButtton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButtton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash></i>';
  trashButtton.classList.add('trash-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButtton);

  //add to main ul class todo-list
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

header,
form {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form input,
form button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
}

form button {
  color: #96e6a1;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

form button:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #96e6a1;
}
```

```html
<title>Worklist</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/konpa/devicon@master/devicon.min.css">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a734bc38d.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>My Todo-List</h1>
  <p>Enjoy this handy website that you can use for free expecially for your todo list.</p>

  <form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="Enter new task" />
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </buton>
            </form>

            <div class="todo-container">
                <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
            </div>

        </main>
```

Comment: Your selectors for `todoButton` and `todoList` are missing the class prefix `.` and are therefore `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fully working `to do list`. There were alot of changes needed in your code.

1. You are not using `preventDefault` method which mean your page `reload` every time you add a new `to do item`
2. You were using the right `class` prefixes `.`
3. You also do not need to have seperate function to call on click. You can use the same `eventlistener` to add to do items.
4. Also, when to do items were getting added you are not displaying the `check` and `trash` icon properly.
5. Also, once the item is added successfully. its `ideal` to set the input to `null` to that another `item` can be added.

**Demo:**

```js
//selectors

const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

//event listener
todoButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  //
  const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");

  //creating the Todo Div
  const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo");

  //creating the LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

  //checkmark button
  const completedButtton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButtton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check></i>';
  completedButtton.classList.add('complete-btn');
  completedButtton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButtton);

  //trash button
  const trashButtton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButtton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  trashButtton.classList.add('trash-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButtton);

  //add to main ul class todo-list
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

  //Clear div
  todoInput.value = ''

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Worklist</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/konpa/devicon@master/devicon.min.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a734bc38d.js"></script>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">   -->
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>My Todo-List</h1>
    <p>Enjoy this handy website that you can use for free expecially for your todo list.</p>

    <form>
      <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="Enter new task" />
      <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
    </form>

    <div class="todo-container">
      <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: this is why I love stackOverflow , except that I am so dumb to tell whats wrong with my code unless other people would see how dumb am I. Thanks a lot

Comment: //event listener
todoButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  event.preventDefault()

Comment: @user13705270 glad to help. Please accept the answer i have helped.

Comment: I really do appreciate those tips. I will keep them in mind, Im still far from reality. @AlwaysHelping  and the guy earlier. seems still needs polishing , I even see conflicts with my JS to bootstrap 4. hahahah but still able to learn small things,  do you have any tips though or workflow when debugging jS?

Comment: @user13705270 Yes, the best handy tool is always look at the `console log` for errors and if you there is nothing in `console` and still not working then try `console.logging `line by line to see where your code stops working.

Comment: You dont need to refetch `todoInput` on each click.